# Registry.GetValue(): Issue with return statement syntax

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winapi

Can someone please tell me what this c# syntax exactly means:

```
return (int)MyPersistenceClass.GetValue(REG_ENTRY_HHHH, DEFAULT_REG_ENTRY_HHHH) == 1
```

Is it correct to say that if (int)GetValue() == 1 return the value. Where I am not sure is what do I return when (int)GetValue() != 1. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are several bits of syntax here.

`MyPersistenceClass.GetValue(REG_ENTRY_HHHH, DEFAULT_REG_ENTRY_HHHH)` is (probably) a static method call to read a value from the registry.

`(int)x` is a cast expression that converts `x` to an `int`, so `(int)MyPersistenceClass.GetValue(REG_ENTRY_HHHH, DEFAULT_REG_ENTRY_HHHH)` converts the value read from the registry to an `int`.

`==` is the [equality operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx).  It compares two things and returns a `bool` value:  `true` if they are the same, `false` if they are not.

`return x` evaluates `x`, makes the result the return value of the function and exits the function.

Putting it all together, your code reads a value from the registry.  The value is converted to an `int` and compared to `1`.  If the value is `1` the function returns `true` otherwise it returns `false`.

Comment: Thanks arx. Your last sentence is all I was looking for but thanks for the explanation. It will definitely help someone else as well.

Answer (score 0):

A simple ternary statement will work for you:

```
return (int)MyPersistenceClass.GetValue(REG_ENTRY_HHHH, DEFAULT_REG_ENTRY_HHHH) == 1 ? 1 : 0;
```

So, if GetValue() == 1, return the value.  Otherwise, return 0.